# How to configure API from the command line using npm?

Tags: javascript, npm, package.json, npm-scripts

I have my mobile app pointing to production URL which is hardcoded in three different javascript files. To be able to configure URL using command line

1. I have added a new config property `base_url` to `package.json` file which has the default production url( `http://www.production.com`).
2. And then setting a `config` property ( `base_url` ) value before running the mobile app using,
   `npm set config base_url`  `http:www.new_url.com`
3. Lastly accessing the base_url in all three javascript file using
   `var API_URL = process.env.npm_package_config_base_url;`

**Problems**:

1. `process.env.npm_package_confi_base_url` is returning `undefined`.
2. Is there any way to pass the url in npm script like,
   `npm run configure_api  --base_url`,
   which will update the `config.base_url` with the value e.g `http://www.domain.docker01.com` and I can access in all javascript file ?

**package.json**

```
{
  "name": "module_name",
  "version": "1.11.0",
  "config": {
    "base_url" : "http://www.production.com"
    }
}
```

Thank you.

Comment: `process.env.npm_package_confi_base_url` Are you sure you typed that right? Also, `process.env` is environment variables. You might find what you're looking for (though no guarantees) in [`process.config`](https://nodejs.org/api/process.html#process_process_config)

Comment: @QPaysTaxes I have fixed the typo. Yes I was using the correct name. The problem is `process` is undefined, so `process.env` or `process.config` would definitely going to return `undefined`.

Comment: If `process` is `undefined`, then you'll get an error, not `undefined` from trying to do member access.